# Rails docker app stops working after some time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, puma

I use the following Dockerfile to create an image for my Rails 4.2 webapp:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.4

ENV LANG C.UTF-8

WORKDIR /usr/src/page

COPY Gemfile .
COPY Gemfile.lock .
RUN bundle install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
ENV CERT_PATH ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?key=certificate.key&cert=certificate.crt
CMD rails server -b $CERT_PATH -e production
```

The Rails app uses the puma (version 3.9.1) webserver.

I create a docker image an run this image as a container on a webserver, which works fine. I can access the webapp via a domain test.example.com or direct via the IP of the server. I use https to access the webapp.

Now the problem:
After visiting a few sites the webapp stops responding (timeout error in browser). I think this happens only when visiting the site via the IP address (https://255.255.255.255/login etc.). However accessing via test.example.com does not work after that.

I have to add the SSL cert is self created.

In the rails logs in the container I see that the last request (which did not work) wasn't even logged, so my guess is it could be a docker problem?

However sudo journalctl -fu docker.service does not seem to show errors.

So my questions: Are there errors in my Dockerfile, are there some known bugs in one of the used software, does anybody know what my problem is, what are some docker commands to find error logs?

Comment: did you try running the container on another host? just in case something is up with networking

Comment: No, I will try it, however ping IP-Address of host is working.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to solve the problem:

```
1) Used newest ruby version
2) Used newest puma version
3) Used puma workers
4) Made a config file for puma
```

For the time being, it seems these things solve the problem.
It appears that docker never made any problems.